# How to disable jQuery Mobile by default

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to add jQuery Mobile to a big project where we need to introduce it slowly and step to step. Unfortunately just adding the script it starts adding styles and behaviours to the page which is already styled etc. crashing everything.

I've seen I can disable things, but I'm moving quite slowly having to disable jQuery Mobile features one by one. Isn't there any option to disable all of it by default and just add the ones I want where I want it? This way including jQuery Mobile to the project would become easier as even adding it to a single page is becoming quite difficult as the page shares styles and behaviour from the rest of the site.

I find it an impressive tool but at the same time quite aggresive on forcing you to have all what it includes.

Thank you.

Comment: what widgets do you want to use? Create a custom jQM library here: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ it wont auto-initialize any widget, so you need to initialize them manually/programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that custom builder. At the moment I'm trying to add just the multiselect feature. It looks like many others are related to this one, but let's see.

Comment: if you add this, you need to call `$( ".selector" ).selectmenu();` to enhance it. Yes, popup and dialog widgets will be included. Because it converts selectmenu into popup or a dialog. You also need to add `data-native-menu="false"` attribute to `select` tag.